# Ext.js combine grid columns and radio buttons

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, extjs

I want to have the options to choose between some payment methods. In my case:

1. Credit cards
2. Bank wired transfer

I need some columns under the radio button Credit Cards: the added credit cards

[Here is an example image of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5aE4.jpg)

Here is what I have so far. This is only the credit cards and the credit card payment method

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                title: 'Your Payment Methods',
                id: 'PMGrid',
                minHeight: 230,
                width: 650,
                viewConfig: {
                    enableTextSelection: true,
                    deferEmptyText: false,
                    emptyText: ' There are no credit cards currently.<br><br> Please add some by pressing the <b>Add Card</b> button.'
                },
                store: mstore1,
                realstore: store1,
                //selModel: { type: 'checkboxmodel' },
                //plugins: 'gridfilters',
                columns: [
                    //{ text: 'No', dataIndex: 'Order', width: 50, filter: { type: 'string' }, align: 'center', },
                    { text: 'Card', dataIndex: 'ccCardNumber', flex: 5, filter: { type: 'string' }, align: 'center', },
                    { text: 'Expires', dataIndex: 'ValidTo', flex: 4.5, xtype: 'datecolumn', format: "m / Y", align: 'center', },
                    {
                        text: 'Default', dataIndex: 'Order', flex: 4, align: 'center', renderer: function (o) {
                            return o == 1 ? '<strong style="color:green">Yes</strong>' : '';
                        }
                    },

                    //{ text: 'Remove', dataIndex: '', width: 90 },
                    //{ text: 'UPO', dataIndex: 'UserPaymentOptionId', width: 80  },
                    //{ text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'HolderName', width: 200  },
                    { text: 'Billing Address', dataIndex: 'BillingAddress', flex: 12, width: 200 },

                ],
                //bbar: { xtype: 'pagingtoolbar', store: mstore1, displayInfo: true, inputItemWidth: 50, doRefresh: function () { store1.reload() } },
                tbar: [
                    //{ text: 'Add New Card', tooltip: 'Add a new card for automated monthly payments', handler: createWin_AddNewCard }, '-',
                    { xtype: 'button', text: 'Add Card', tooltip: 'Add new card', width: 120, handler: function () { Ext.getCmp('AddCard').show() } }, '-',
                    { text: 'Remove Card', id: 'bRemove', tooltip: 'Remove selected cards', width: 120, handler: RemoveUPOClick, disabled: true }, '-',
                    { text: 'Set Default', id: 'bDefault', tooltip: 'Set Default and move to top', width: 120, handler: Move2TopClick, disabled: true },
                ]
```

Comment: Please dont spam language tags or show relevant code, if there is any (c#, asp.net).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using rowexpander plugin to achieve your use case.Refer the documentation https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.grid.plugin.RowExpander.html

Here is an example,

```
Ext.application({
name: 'Fiddle',
launch: function () {
    var mstore1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: [
            'paymentMethod',
            'ccCardNumber',
            'ValidTo',
            'Order',
            'BillingAddress',
            'addedColumn1',
            'addedColumn2'
        ],
        data: [{
            paymentMethod: 'Credit Cards Payment',
            ccCardNumber: '**** **** **** 1234',

            ValidTo: '12/2025',
            Order: 1,
            BillingAddress: '1234 Street, City',
            addedColumn1: 'Value 1',
            addedColumn2: 'Value 2'
        }, {
            paymentMethod: 'Bank Wired Transfer',
            ccCardNumber: '**** **** **** 5678',
            ValidTo: '06/2024',
            Order: 0,
            BillingAddress: '5678 Avenue, Town',
            addedColumn1: 'Value 3',
            addedColumn2: 'Value 4'
        }]
    });
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'Your Payment Methods',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        id: 'PMGrid',
        minHeight: 230,
        width: 650,
        store: mstore1,
        plugins: {
            rowexpander: {
                rowBodyTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                    '<div class="btn-group">',
                    '<button>Add Card</button>',
                    '<button>Remove Card</button>',
                    '<button>Set Default</button>',
                    '</div>',
                    '<table>',
                    '<th>Card</th>',
                    '<th>Expires</th>',
                    '<th>Default</th>',
                    '<th>Billing Address</th>',
                    '<tr>',
                    '<td>{ccCardNumber}</td>',
                    '<td>{ValidTo}</td>',
                    '<td>{[values.Order === 1 ? "Yes" : ""]}</td>',
                    '<td>{BillingAddress}</td>',
                    '</tr>',
                    '</table>'
                ),
            }
        },
        columns: [{
            text: 'Your Payment Methods',
            dataIndex: 'paymentMethod',
            flex: 1,
            filter: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            align: 'center',
            renderer: function (value) {
                return value.replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, "*"); // Masking the card number
            }
        }],
    });
}
```

});

CSS code:

```
td,th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

.btn-group button {
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.x-grid-cell-inner {
    text-align: left !important;
}


.x-grid-row-collapsed .x-grid-row-expander:before {
    content: '\f111' !important;
}

.x-grid-row-expander::before {
      content: "\f192" !important;
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image: OUTPUT]